# PowerShell: Store Entire Text File Contents in Variable

Tags: powershell

I'd like to use PowerShell to store the *entire* contents of a text file (including the trailing blank line that may or may not exist) in a variable. I'd also like to know the total number of lines in the text file. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

To get the entire contents of a file:

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\test.txt")
```

Number of lines:

```
([IO.File]::ReadAllLines(".\test.txt")).length
```

or

```
(gc .\test.ps1).length
```

Sort of hackish to include trailing empty line:

```
[io.file]::ReadAllText(".\desktop\git-python\test.ps1").split("`n").count
```

Comment: Thanks! `$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\test.txt")` appears to do the same thing as `$content = (gc ".\test.txt" | out-string)`. Since the second of the two is shorter, that's what I prefer.

Unfortunately, neither of the methods you provided for calculating the total number of lines takes trailing blank lines into consideration. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Nick In .Net (and windows), any line with `\r\n` will be counted.

Comment: I was doing some experimenting and came up with the same thing as your updated answer, but I wouldn't have gotten there without your help, so thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to transparently combine this with `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Answer (score 264):

On a side note, in PowerShell 3.0 you can use the `Get-Content` cmdlet with the new Raw switch:

```
$text = Get-Content .\file.txt -Raw
```

Comment: This is should be the accepted answer. By the way, I'm pretty sure Get-Content worked even in earlier versions.

Comment: @MatteoSp `Get-Content` did, but it wasn't until 3.0 that it got `-Raw`. Without that, it gets stored as a array of lines.

Comment: This should absolutely be the accepted answer. It doesn't help that the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx) says that the `-Raw` parameter isn't implemented by anything native.

Comment: This does not fully answer the original question (needs to add how to calculate line numbers).  It is a useful piece of information though.

Answer (score 32):

### Powershell 2.0:

[(see detailed explanation here)](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/10/21/why-get-content-aint-yer-friend/comment-page-1/)

```
$text = Get-Content $filePath | Out-String
```

The `IO.File.ReadAllText` didn't work for me with a relative path, it looks for the file in `%USERPROFILE%\$filePath` instead of the current directory (when running from Powershell ISE at least):

```
$text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($filePath)
```

### Powershell 3+:

```
$text = Get-Content $filePath -Raw
```

Comment: To use relatives paths, resolve it first eg: `[IO.File]::ReadAllText((Resolve-Path $filePath))`

Answer (score 17):

One more approach to reading a file that I happen to like is referred to variously as *variable notation* or *variable syntax* and involves simply enclosing a filespec within curly braces preceded by a dollar sign, to wit:

```
$content = ${C:file.txt}
```

This notation may be used as either [an L-value or an R-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29); thus, you could just as easily write to a file with something like this:

```
 ${D:\path\to\file.txt} = $content
```

Another handy use is that you can modify a file in place without a temporary file and without sub-expressions, for example:

```
${C:file.txt} = ${C:file.txt} | select -skip 1
```

I became fascinated by this notation initially because it was very difficult to find out anything about it! Even the PowerShell 2.0 specification mentions it only once showing just one line using it--but with no explanation or details of use at all. I have subsequently found this blog entry on [PowerShell variables](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/3790-working-with-powershell-variables.aspx) that gives some good insights.

One final note on using this: you must use a drive designation, i.e. `${drive:filespec}` as I have done in all the examples above. Without the drive (e.g. `${file.txt}`) it does not work. No restrictions on the filespec on that drive: it may be absolute or relative.

Comment: I have never got this to work unless I put a backslash after the drive name.

Comment: @CharlesAnderson: It is not clear which of the three examples you are referring to, or perhaps all of them... nonetheless, I just confirmed that all 3 work with a relative path (i.e. no backslash) in PowerShell V3. Further, at the time of my answer I was using V2, so perhaps there is something else causing an issue in your environment.

Comment: I meant examples like ${C:file.txt}, which I have to write as ${C:\file.txt}. Yes, I presume it is something about my environment, but I have no idea what.

Comment: When using as L-value, it uses the system's default encoding.
I tried to set $OutputEncoding with no effect.

When using as R-value, it produces a string[] array.

Comment: It seems you can only use a literal pathname; you can't use a variable or something like a Join-Path expression inside this. Which is annoying, because when piped through ConvertTo-Json, there is a world of difference compared with Get-Content (and the ${...} result is what I was hoping for. I'm not sure if this is the same as Get-Content | Out-String though

Comment: @CameronKerr Yes that seems to be the case. I might just edit this answer to note that.

Comment: How do I get this to work on a filesystem that doesn't have drives, like on UNIX systems? I'm using Powershell 7.2.5 on Linux. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Get-Content grabs data and dumps it into an array, line by line.  Assuming there aren't other special requirements than you listed, you could just save your content into a variable?

```
$file = Get-Content c:\file\whatever.txt
```

Running just `$file` will return the full contents.  Then you can just do `$file.Count` (because arrays already have a count method built in) to get the total # of lines.

Hope this helps!  I'm not a scripting wiz, but this seemed easier to me than a lot of the stuff above.

Answer (score 1):

### Read binary file:

This is not exactly what was asked, but some might find this useful for their use case anyway. `Get-Content -Raw` yields a `string`, so if you want `byte[]`:

```
Get-Content c:\file.bin -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0
```

`-Read-Count` tells how many lines go through the pipeline at a time (default is 1), and 0 does everything in one operation which boosts performance.

The credits shall go to Shay Levy who has published this solution: [(see Shay's post here)](https://powershellmagazine.com/2014/03/17/pstip-reading-file-content-as-a-byte-array/)